How to create a custom input in React JS (infinite rendering loops)
I want to create a custom input with encapsulated logic in React, but I am having an issue during the process, which is an infinite loop of renderings. Below I attached an example code where I have some state for input. The problem is that when I am changing a value of Child input it tries to update a state of Parent component which is in his case updates the state of Cild component and it continues forever. how to solve the problem of infinite rendering loops?
const InputWithValidation = ({ value, onChange }) => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(value);
    const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

    const handleInternalOnChange = (e) => {
        // dummy action for demo
        setInputValue(`__${e.target.value}`);
        setIsValid(isValidMaxLength(e.target.value, 10) && e.target.value !== '');
    }

    // sync with parent state
    useEffect(() => {
        setInputValue(value)
    }, [value])

    // notify parent 
    useEffect(() => {
        if (onChange)
            onChange(inputValue, isValid);
    }, [inputValue, isValid, onChange])

    return (
        <input value={inputValue} onChange={handleInternalOnChange} />
    )
}

export default InputWithValidation

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('abc');

    const handleOnChange = (val, isValid) => {
        setValue(val);
        console.log(isValid);
    }

    return (<InputWithValidation value={value} onChange={handleOnChange} />)
}

I've tried to solve the problem using memo, but it doesn't work.

        setInputValue(value)
    }, [value])``` this line is the problem

usually it would be best to decide if you want to store value in this component or in parent components... because its best practice, to have Single Source of truth

@Mechanic yes you're right. but I need to do this because I manage complex logic in custom component. this is just a simplified example to demonstrate a problem

@Mycroft - It doesn't really matter how complex the logic is, the state can still come from the parent. The logic can be applied in the event handler and possibly useMemo callbacks (if it's really complicated).

Either InputWithValidation should have the value of the input in state or ParentComponent should, but not both. Often it would be the latter, a case of lifting state up.
That's probably true in your example, the state should probably be held in ParentComponent. Then, InputWithValidation doesn't have value and even its validity flag isn't a state value, the component becomes completely stateless because isValid is derived information.
const InputWithValidation = ({ value, onChange }) => {
    const handleInternalOnChange = (e) => {
        const newValue = e.target.value;
        const isValid = isValidMaxLength(newValue, 10) && newValue !== "";
        onChange(newValue, isValid);
    };

    return (
        <input value={value} onChange={handleInternalOnChange} />
    )
};

You've said in a comment that the actual logic is more complex, but that probably doesn't matter, the above — like your original — is only doing that logic when the value changes, prior (in this case) to notifying the parent (since in your question you show passing isValid to the provided onChange callback). If you needed to calculate complex information purely on the basis of the value prop (rather than in the event handler), you could still do that in a useMemo callback.
